# Testing Typescript Interface with Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, create-react-app

Below is my interface and test file.  When I run jest tests against it for code coverage, it keeps saying that lines 1 and 2 are not covered by the tests.  Is code coverage for interfaces something that is even possible? Or should I exclude any interfaces from the coverage reports?

`index.tsx`

```
export interface StoreState {
    languageName: string;
    enthusiasmLevel: number;
}
```

`index.test.tsx`

```
import { StoreState } from '../types';

it('has a languageName of "TypeScript"', () => {
    const state: StoreState = { languageName: 'TypeScript', enthusiasmLevel: 3 };
    expect(state.languageName).toEqual('TypeScript');
});

it('has an enthusiasm level of 3', () => {
  const state: StoreState = { languageName: 'TypeScript', enthusiasmLevel: 3 };
  expect(state.enthusiasmLevel).toEqual(3);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known issue with `ts-jest` ([Issue #378](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/378)). The project owners currently recommend excluding interface files from Jest coverage:

***kulshekhar*** commented on Jan 1, 2018:

> I don't think there's anything that can be done in ts-jest to fix this. I've taken a closer look at this issue and there are two ways to get the desired outcome:
>
> - exclude files that contain only types from coverage
> - add and export a dummy function/variable from a file that contains only types
>
> When TypeScript transpiles files, it doesn't convert 'pure type' imports to `require` statements. This results in Jest not picking and passing those files to ts-jest.

***GeeWee*** commented on Jan 2, 2018:

> I don't think we can exclude files that contain only types. I also think this is a wontfix unless jest adds the capabillity for transformers to opt files out of coverage or something akin to that.

For example, you could use [`coveragePathIgnorePatterns`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#coveragepathignorepatterns-array-string) to exclude files based on a naming convention for files that contain only types (e.g., an `I` prefix followed by a capital letter, such as "`ISerializable`"):

```
{
  "jest": {
    ...
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "**/I[A-Z]*.{ts}"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: For me, I needed to use the following regexp: "src/*/I[A-z]*.ts". Double '*' resulted in an Error.

Comment: Thanks @Sophia! This worked for me "<rootDir>/.+/I[A-z]+.ts"